# How to get the weeks counted from the given date?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have a scenario where the user can select the start date and end date.
I should be displaying the data week wise from his start date to end date where week 1 -should contain the data from his start date to end date of that particular week ,
week 2 - should be the next weeks data. and so on
how will I show this as week 1 if the start date selected by the user is 22-jun-16?

Comment: Plz show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Hi Avrajit, I did not get how to put week 1 .As 22 -jun -16 falls into week3 it is automatically shown by 'w' .

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided any table structure I am creating the following table for explaining the solution.

```
CREATE TABLE sales
(
sale_date DATE,
sale_amt NUMBER(20,2)
)
```

Now, insert some sample data in this table.

You can use the following query to get week-wise data.

```
SELECT wk_start, 
       sale_amt, 
       'Week ' || ROWNUM
FROM
(
SELECT wk_start, 
       sale_amt
FROM ( SELECT TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw') wk_start, 
              SUM(sale_amt) sale_amt 
       FROM   sales
       WHERE sale_date BETWEEN '06/23/2016' AND '08/05/2016'
       GROUP BY TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')
     )
ORDER BY wk_start
)
```

The inner most query will get the first day of the week for any date in your table along with the total sales (or any other measure) for that week. Then we are ordering the results of the inner most query by Week Start date and prefixing the string Week to it.

Here is the enhanced solution to suit your exact requirement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 1 THEN TO_DATE('06/23/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') ELSE wk_start END AS wk_start,
       mon,
       row_number() over(partition by mon order by rownum) as week_num,
       sale_amt 
FROM
( SELECT TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')-1 wk_start, 
             TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')-1, 'MON') mon, 
             SUM(sale_amt) sale_amt 
       FROM   sales
       WHERE sale_date BETWEEN '06/23/2016' AND '08/05/2016'
       GROUP BY TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')-1, 
                TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')-1, 'MON') 
       ORDER BY TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')-1 
     )
ORDER BY wk_start
```

The inner query is getting the month of the week start date. The row_number() function will increment the week number until the month remains the same. Once the month changes it will reset it to 1. The first line of the main query will display the parameter which you have passed instead of the week start date for the first row. For all the remaining rows it will print the week start date.

The below query will format the dates as per your requirement. If you require any additional fields to the query include them SELECT list of all the queries and GROUP BY list of the inner most query.

```
SELECT 
'Week ' || week_num || '(' || to_char(wk_start,'dd-mon-yyyy') || ' to ' || to_char(wk_end,'dd-mon-yyyy') || ')' as Week,
sale_amt 
FROM
(
SELECT CASE WHEN ROWNUM = 1 THEN TO_DATE('06/23/2016','MM/DD/YYYY') ELSE wk_start END AS wk_start,
       wk_end AS wk_end,
       mon,
       row_number() over(partition by mon order by rownum) as week_num,
       sale_amt 
FROM
( SELECT TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')-1 wk_start, 
         TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')+5 wk_end,
         TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')-1, 'MON') mon, 
         SUM(sale_amt) sale_amt 
       FROM   sales
       WHERE sale_date BETWEEN '06/23/2016' AND '08/05/2016'
       GROUP BY TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')-1, 
                TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')+5,
                TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')-1, 'MON') 
       ORDER BY TRUNC(sale_date ,'iw')-1 
     )
ORDER BY wk_start
)
```

Comment: Hi, You tried appending the Rownum to the week but I don't want that.I wanted the week count starting from the start date .example: the start date and end date from your code are '06/23/2016' AND '08/05/201'- I wanted to show 23-06-16 to 25-06-16 for week1 , 26-06-16 to 02-07-16 as week2 and 03-07-16 to 09-07-16 as week 1 again(since a diff month) ..please help

Comment: @lakshmitatavarty, I have added a new solution in my original answer. Please check.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer.                                                                   Week                                          News Id News  Total Views
Week 1(15June 2016 to 18 june 2016) 501  aaaa 33
Week 2 (19June 2016 to 25 june 2016) 501 aaaa 34
Week 3 (26 June 2016 to 2july 2016) 501 aaaa 55
Week 1(3july 2016 to 9 july 2016)         501   aaaa  4
Week 2(10 July 2016 to 16 july 2016) 502 bbbbbbbbb 33
This way I require the output  when start date is given as 15-jun-16 and end date is given as 16-july-16

Comment: @lakshmitatavarty. I have added a new solution which includes the end dates and date formatting. You can add any additional fields to the query.